# How to transform a List[Tuple2[X,Y]] to a Map[X, List[Y]] to avoid duplicates in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, group-by, scala-collections

I am trying to figure out how to transform a List of tuples to a Map using *groupBy*. Let's say I am retrieving the list from DB this way :

```
val results: List[(Author, Book)] = getAuthorAndBook()
```

since, an author may have written many books, I may have the same author with different books in this list so I would like to group the books by author and have a Map[Author, List[Book]] instead.

how can I achieve that ?

I know I have to group but then after that, I am not quite sure how to deal with the Books

```
results.groupBy(_._1) // and then what ?
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
results.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

groupBy creates a Map with the desired keys, but the values still have the keys in them, they are List[(X, Y)] instead of List[Y]. The mapValues call fixes this.

Comment: just figured it out too thanks a lot :) ... the REPL is definitely my friend ;)

Answer (score -1):

There's a build-in function that does it for lists of Tuple2.

```
val list = List( (1,"toto") , (2,"test") )
list: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,toto), (2,test))

list.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,toto), (2,test))
```

You don't need what wingedsubmariner suggest, it's already handled for you.

Comment: Doesn't work if the author writes more than one book. The value needs to be a list of the second item of each tuple.`val list = List( (1,"toto") , (2,"test") , (2, "wibble"));
                                                  //> list  : List[(Int, String)] = List((1,toto), (2,test), (2,wibble))
val r = list.toMap;                               //> r  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> toto, 2 -> wibble)`

Comment: that's right, sorry I thought it is was about to get a `Map[Int,String]` and not a `Map[Int,List[String]]`